Albanese map and curve
Let $S$ be a complex projective integral separated smooth surface (as a scheme). I consider the albanese map $\alpha : S \mapsto A$. I suppose $\alpha(S)$ is a smooth curve of genus $h^{1}(\mathcal{O}_{S}) > 0$ and the fiber of $\alpha$ are connected.
Is it possible that there is an infinity of exceptional curve $C_{1}, C_{2}, ...$ on $S$ (so that are smooth with self intersection $-1$) such that $C_{i}$ is in a fiber of $\alpha$ for each $i$?

Their are perhaps too much hypothesis but perhaps we need that?

No that is not possible. Each such curve has at least one point where the rank of $d\alpha$ is zero.  The rank zero locus is a Zariski closed subset, hence quasi-compact, hence finitely many points.

So you are using the analytic point of view? Why does each curve as a point where $d\alpha$ is of rank $0$?  I agree the rank locus is Zariski closed since it is locally a solution of polynomial but it could be of dimension $1$ and hence not finite?

The rank zero locus is a Zariski closed subset.  It has finitely many irreducible components of dimension one and finitely many isolated points.  By generic smoothness / Sard’s theorem, all of these are contained in finitely many fibers.

OK, I get this point. But why each curve contains a point where d$\alpha = 0$?

If the fiber is smooth, then the self intersection equals zero.  So if the self intersection is negative, then the curve contains at least one singular point of the fiber.

Is it easy to prove that any curve of negative self intersection contains a point where $d\alpha = 0$?

I don't see the link with smoothness and my definition of intersection.

I do not understand your comment.  You asked about $(-1)$ curves that are contained in fibers.  I explained why such a curve contains a singular point of the fiber.  Other $(-1)$ curves, that are not contained in fibers, might contain nonsingular point of a fiber.

Yes, but I don't understand your explanation. With my definition of the intersection, I don't see why a smooth fiber must contain only curve of 0 self intersection.

For a smooth fiber, the differential $d\alpha$ from the tangent bundle of the surface to the pullback of the tangent bundle of the normalization of the image of $\alpha$ factors through the normal bundle of the fiber in the surface.  The induced homomorphism from the normal bundle to the pullback of the tangent bundle is an isomorphism if the fiber is smooth.  Since the normal bundle is a pullback, the degree of the normal bundle equals zero.

OK, now it's clear enough! Many thanks!
